# Add product to the cart with attached custom line items

Tags: commerce

I need to add a product with some additional custom line items programatically. The source for the custom line items are text fields.

This is my code used in submit function

```
    function my_add_to_cart_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
      global $user;
      $product_id = $form_state['values']['product_id'];

      // Put the product in the cart
      $order = _create_order_with_product($product_id, $user->uid, TRUE);

      // The code below has to add custom line items, but does not.

      // Create empty line item
      $line_item = commerce_line_item_new('product', $order->order_id);
      $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
      $line_item_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $line_item);

      // Set Line Item Label
      $line_item_wrapper->line_item_label = t('Custom Line item');

      // Set quantity
      $line_item_wrapper->quantity = 1;

      // Set Line Item price
      $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->amount = '400';

      // Set Line Item currency
      $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->currency_code = 'USD';

      // Save price data
      $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->data = commerce_price_component_add(
        $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->value(),
        'base_price',
        $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->value(),
        TRUE,
        FALSE
      );

      // Save the item in DB
      commerce_line_item_save($line_item);

      // Add to the order.
      $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;

      // Save order again
      commerce_order_save($order);



    }

    function _create_order_with_product($product_id, $uid, $use_cart = TRUE) {
      $order = commerce_cart_order_load($uid);

      if (empty($order)) {
        $order = commerce_order_new($uid, 'checkout_checkout');
        commerce_order_save($order);
      }

      $product = commerce_product_load($product_id);
      $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1, $order->order_id);
      commerce_line_item_save($line_item);

      $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
      $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;

      commerce_order_save($order);
      return $order;
   }
```

So now I have the following result:

1) On "/cart" page fatal error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unable to get the data property
>   product_id as the parent data structure is not set. in
>   EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyValue() (line 442 of
>   C:\wamp\www\work2\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc).

2) Product and custom line items saved in DB

3) No orders available on "admin/commerce/orders" page

Please help to understand where is mistake.

Comment: As I understand i have to provide another line item type whish is no product, using hook_commerce_line_item_type_info() Am I right?

Comment: yes, it because u have  no product in your lineitems